# TableColumns not visible in TableView but visible in Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am facing a strange Problem. I am working with the latest Gluon SceneBuilder for JavaFX.

In my Scene i have a Tableview with 11 Columns. All the Colums are visible in the Scene Builder but as soon as I run the Application, there is no Column visible. There is just a blank bar where the given Column names should be. And Yes, i did Refresh after saving SceneBuilder FXML file.

The Scene Builder Settings including Controller and fx:id's for TableColumns and TableView are correct. What am i missing?

SceneBuilder Preview:

[image]

Real life:

[image]

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1150.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="arrivals.ArrivalsController">
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints percentHeight="5.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <RowConstraints percentHeight="5.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <children>
      <HBox GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label text="Show Period" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="periodBox" onAction="#populateTable" prefWidth="150.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </ChoiceBox>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Separator>
            <Label text="From" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <DatePicker fx:id="from" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </DatePicker>
            <Label text="To" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <DatePicker fx:id="to" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </DatePicker>
            <Button minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#picker" text="Show">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <TableView fx:id="arvtable" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="bookingId" prefWidth="75.0" text="Booking ID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="firstName" prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="lastName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="arrival" prefWidth="75.0" text="Arrival" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="checkout" prefWidth="75.0" text="Checkout" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="roomNumber" prefWidth="75.0" text="Room Number" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="roomType" prefWidth="75.0" text="Room Type" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="nights" prefWidth="75.0" text="Nights" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="breakfast" prefWidth="75.0" text="Breakfast" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="amount" prefWidth="75.0" text="Amount" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="comment" prefWidth="75.0" text="Comments" />
         </columns></TableView>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Button minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Modify">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Cancel">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Check-In">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children></HBox>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class ArrivalsController implements Initializable{

    final ObservableList<ArrivalRecord> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @FXML   TableView<ArrivalRecord> arvtable;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> bookingId;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> firstName;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> lastName;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> arrival;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> checkout;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> roomNumber;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> roomType;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> nights;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> breakfast;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> amount;
    @FXML   TableColumn<ArrivalRecord, String> comment;




    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        bookingId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getBidProperty());
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFirstNameProperty());
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getLastNameProperty());
        arrival.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getArrivalProperty());
        checkout.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCheckoutProperty());
        roomNumber.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRoomNumberProperty());
        roomType.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRoomTypeProperty());
        nights.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNightsProperty());
        breakfast.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getBreakfastProperty());
        amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getAmountProperty());
        comment.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCommentProperty());

    }
```

Data Model:

```
public class ArrivalRecord {


    final StringProperty bid;
    final StringProperty firstName;
    final StringProperty lastName;
    final StringProperty arrival;
    final StringProperty checkout;
    final StringProperty roomNumber;
    final StringProperty roomType;
    final StringProperty nights;
    final StringProperty breakfast;
    final StringProperty amount;
    final StringProperty comment;


    ArrivalRecord(String bid, String firstName, String lastName,
            String arrival, String checkout, String roomNumber,
            String roomType, String nights, String breakfast,
            String amount, String comment) {

        this.bid = new SimpleStringProperty(bid);
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.arrival = new SimpleStringProperty(arrival);
        this.checkout = new SimpleStringProperty(checkout);
        this.roomNumber = new SimpleStringProperty(roomNumber);
        this.roomType = new SimpleStringProperty(roomType);
        this.nights = new SimpleStringProperty(nights);
        this.breakfast = new SimpleStringProperty(breakfast);
        this.amount = new SimpleStringProperty(amount);
        this.comment = new SimpleStringProperty(comment);
    }


    public String getBid() {
        return bid.get();
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }


    public String getArrival() {
        return arrival.get();
    }


    public String getCheckout() {
        return checkout.get();
    }


    public String getRoomNumber() {
        return roomNumber.get();
    }


    public String getRoomType() {
        return roomType.get();
    }


    public String getNights() {
        return nights.get();
    }


    public String getBreakfast() {
        return breakfast.get();
    }


    public String getAmount() {
        return amount.get();
    }


    public String getComment() {
        return comment.get();
    }

    public StringProperty getBidProperty() {
        return bid;
    }


    public StringProperty getFirstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public StringProperty getLastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public StringProperty getArrivalProperty() {
        return arrival;
    }


    public StringProperty getCheckoutProperty() {
        return checkout;
    }


    public StringProperty getRoomNumberProperty() {
        return roomNumber;
    }


    public StringProperty getRoomTypeProperty() {
        return roomType;
    }


    public StringProperty getNightsProperty() {
        return nights;
    }


    public StringProperty getBreakfastProperty() {
        return breakfast;
    }


    public StringProperty getAmountProperty() {
        return amount;
    }


    public StringProperty getCommentProperty() {
        return comment;
    }


}
```

Comment: It runs fine for me, I don't see any issue

Comment: Same here (after removing not existing functions from FXML) works like a charm

Comment: hmm.. strange! not working on my computer for some reason! anyways thanks for the information!

Comment: One possible explanation is that your IDE has not re-deployed the FXML file to the build/output directory after you edited it in Scene Builder. Check the contents of the build folder (i.e. the one containing .class files, not .java files) and make sure that the FXML file there is at least as recent as the one in the source folder. If not (or, just try this anyway), clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: cleaning and rebuilding did it. thanks. it works now =)